# How do I use Rajdhani font?? It's not an existing font in texmaker

Tags: texmaker

https://fonts.google.com/specimen/

Just fillinf out

```
%%-\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{xcolor} %% THIS ONE IS USED FOR THE COLOUR MIX E.G. BlUE + BLACK
\definecolor{payne\'sgrey}{rgb}{0.25, 0.25, 0.28} %% OR define color == full list == http://latexcolor.com/
    \definecolor{sapphire}{rgb}{0.03, 0.15, 0.4}
        \definecolor{platinum}{rgb}{0.9, 0.89, 0.89}
\newcommand\crule[3][black]{\textcolor{#1}{\rule{#2}{#3}}}
```

Comment: your link does not link to anywhere but if you install the font in your operating system, you can use lualatex or xelatex to access the font,

Answer (score 3):

The google font site is mainly set up for web fonts however

The fonts are available in a zip file from the original sources on github

https://github.com/itfoundry/rajdhani/releases

if I just unpack that to the current directory I can use it in xelatex as

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Rajdhani-Regular.otf}

\begin{document}

hello world  हैलो वर्ल्ड 

\end{document}
```

producing

[image]

Probably babel or polyglossia packages have more extensive support for languages using Devanagari script, but even without it's possible to typeset the basic text as shown above. (I hope the text says hello world, I can't read it)

Comment: Once again, we cross!

Comment: +1 (and yes the text does say "hello world"), but on Mac OS the line `\setmainfont{Rajdhani-Regular.otf}` fails: it should be just `\setmainfont{Rajdhani-Regular}` (or `\setmainfont{Rajdhani-Regular.ttf}` which works on lualatex but not xelatex). (And you're right, the text layout is wrong in lualatex… instead of using well-tested libraries like harfbuzz, lualatex has the ambitious goal of implementing all text layout by itself in lua code to minimize dependencies, which means that it doesn't support most Indic scripts and supports Devanagari somewhat poorly.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR the `Rajdhani-2_000.zip`  file from github has the files in OpenType forn with `.otf` filenames, perhaps you have a version from google or elsewhere that has them as truetype and .ttf? as for harfbuzz yes, long term hope to get that working there are experiments that look promising but not generally usable yet unfortunately https://github.com/search?q=harfbuzz+luatex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah yes, I had downloaded from https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Rajdhani (as in the other answer) rather than from the github link. Now it makes sense. And as for the great combination of luatex+harfbuzz, I eagerly look forward to it becoming more usable :-)

Answer (score 2):

The correct link adds "Rajdhani":

https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Rajdhani

From there, you select the font, then click on the black box where you made the selection, then click on the download icon. You will get a zip file with the TrueType fonts.

Unzip, place the Radjani folder in your texmf-local or texmf-home directory (whatever it is named, which varies with distribution and setup).

Use LuaLaTeX to compile. Note that you do not `\usepackage{Radjhani}` since there is no such package. Instead, `fontspec` will automatically find it:

```
% !TeX program = LuaLaTeX
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Rajdhani}
\begin{document}
This text is in Rajdhani font.
\end{document}
```

It is that simple. If you need to use additional fonts, see the `fontspec` documentation.

[image: text in Radjhani font]

Comment: I suspect that you will find xelatex handles this better (the example in my answer looks noticeably different in lualatex)