RomDev map and LuaLaTex
So far, most of my real work uses IAST for Sanskrit display. But I would like to produce Devanāgarī output as well, for which I was thinking to to use the RomDev map. The following document compiles fine with XeLaTeX, but I get only boxes if I try to compile it with LuaLaTex:
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{sanskrit}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\sanskritfont{Latin Modern Roman}

\newfontfamily\sanskritdeva[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=RomDev]{Noto Serif Devanagari}

\begin{document}

\begin{sanskritdeva}
\begin{verse}
sarvajñatādiguṇagocaramāyayau yā\\
dhyeyā yato 'pi yatibandhurabodhi bodhiḥ|\\
sā satyanirdhutacaturvidhavibhramārtir\\
mūrtirdṛśāṃ diśatu dāśabalī śivaṃ vaḥ||
\end{verse}
\end{sanskritdeva}

\end{document}

The error messages are all of the following kind:
Missing character: There is no s (U+0073) in font NotoSerifDevanagari:mode=harf
;script=dev2;language=dflt;!

Is it at all possible to use the RomDev map with LuaLaTex, or would I have to stick to XeLaTex for that?

You should contact the author via your github link about this. As the description states: "(...) convert UTF8 Romanized Sanskrit and Prakrit to Devanagari in XeLaTeX."

Do you need to enter the text using a latin script transliteration? Using lualtaex or xelatex you could enter the devanagari directly eg https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/365792/1090

Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/285610/4427 help?

Map files do not work with lualatex. There you need a transliteration. babel has a few, e.g. (I don't know if it does everything correctly, but such transliterations can be adapted):
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelprovide[transforms=transliteration.iast]{sanskrit}
\babelfont{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz]{Noto Serif Devanagari}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{sanskrit}
\begin{verse}
sarvajñatādiguṇagocaramāyayau yā\\
dhyeyā yato 'pi yatibandhurabodhi bodhiḥ|\\
sā satyanirdhutacaturvidhavibhramārtir\\
mūrtirdṛśāṃ diśatu dāśabalī śivaṃ vaḥ||
\end{verse}
\end{document}



Nice! It even automatically swallows the spaces between words ending in consonants and starting with a vowel. However, so far it works only for a MWE, not yet for a real world file which I'd apparently need to switch from polyglossia to babel, and in which reledmac adds another layer of complexity. I'll have to see if I can get that to work.

Here is a follow-up question about how to get this to work with reledmac.
